# Tool to manage i18n strings

Tags: c#, resources, internationalization

We must manage thousands of internationalized strings for a large application.
What tools do you recommend besides using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use several resource files if you can separate them in some logical parts that make sense to the application.

Second, a tool that I use always is [Zeta Resource Editor](http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/) (Open Source)

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ZetaResourceEditor&DownloadId=40997](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=ZetaResourceEditor&DownloadId=40997)